# ¿Cómo hacer que mi APP lance notificaciones cada cierto tiempo en Android?

Tags: java, android-studio, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

Necesito si alguien me puede explicar cómo mandar notificaciones cada cierto tiempo por ejemplo cada hora.

Más o menos se que se necesita 'broadcast receiver' para que se mantenga funcionando la app aun cerrada y también un 'alarm manager' pero la verdad tengo muy poco conocimiento de cómo manejar estas dos clases si me pudieran explicar con un ejemplo que posean se los agradecería demasiado.

Comment: Podrías revisar [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 1):

Idealmente programarias un servidor para este trabajo, este servidor estaria funcionando 24/7 verificando el intervalo de tiempo y enviar la notificacion cuando sea necesario.

Si te parece inconveniente dejar tu ordenador encendido 24/7 hay opciones como un [Virtual Desktop](https://aws.amazon.com) de amazon, el cual practicamente tienes un ordenador que accedes virtualmente desde el tuyo. Y este se quedaria encendido 24/7 corriendo el servidor que hayas programado, aun cuando tu ordenador **no** este encendido.